# Lifting DG-categories to characteristic zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, dg-categories

The question of lifting (smooth projective) varieties from an algebraically closed  field $k$ of characteristic $p$ to characteristic zero (i.e., to the Witt vectors $W(k)$) is a classical one. It's known since the 60s that a lifting need not necessarily exist.

I'd like to know if there are natural examples of this phenomenon to keep in mind when works at the level of the derived (DG or stable) categories.

More specifically, consider a $k$-linear DG category or stable $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ which has reasonable finiteness hypotheses. For instance, $\mathcal{C}$ could be smooth and proper. Are there natural counterexamples to the following statement: there exists a $W(k)$-linear DG category $\mathcal{C}'$ with analogous finiteness conditions such that $\mathcal{C}' \otimes_{W(k)} k \simeq \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: can we not take something silly, like a known X for which there's no lift to Witt vectors -- but taken in such a way that X is Fano (or anti-Fano) so that its derived category recovers it completely. Hmm, wait, I guess that if there were an abstract DG-category lifting D(X) it would be some sort of non-commutative lift. Now that I think of it there should some work of Kaledin on this topic.

Comment: Akhil, I'm afraid that I don't have an answer to your question. If ${\cal C}$ has one object (so that you are lifting DGAs), the moduli of DGAs over $k$ is governed by Andre-Quillen cohomology groups for associative $k$-algebras, and the moduli of DGAs lifted to $W(k)$ is governed by Andre-Quillen cohomology groups for associative $k$-algebras with a Bockstein operator ($k \otimes_{W(k)} k$-coalgebras); the "difference" is a moduli of liftings to coalgebras. However, to try and compare them you need to identify a potential example, and I don't have any intuition for that.

Comment: @TylerLawson: I should clarify that I am interested in the stable case (so in your example, that would correspond to lifting modulo Morita equivalence). I am also interested in the question you raise, but I suspect there are counterexamples in the discrete case.

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that. Sorry!

Comment: Maybe something along the following lines -- take a smooth projective $X$ over $k$ with a non-closed global differential form, and $p>\dim X$. By the assumption on $p$ for the category $\mathcal{C}=\rm{Perf}(X)$ there is a canonical isomorphism $HH_i(\mathcal{C})=\oplus H^p(X,\Omega^{p+i})$ where Connes differential on the LHS coincides with the de Rham differential on the LHS. Thus, Hochschild-to-cyclic spectral sequence does not degenerate at the first page so $\mathcal{C}$ cannot be liftable already over $W_2(k)$.